# Finding when an Iframe's content changes when in designMode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, midas-editor

I have an Iframe which I have enabled [designMode](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midas-spec.html) on. Quite simply I would like to have a callback function called if the cursor in the Iframe moves or content changes. It seemed quite simple at first but I can't use onchange/ onkeyup on the Iframe.

I assume I need to add an event to a member of the Iframe. I've tried

```
frames['writer'].document.body.onkeyup = eventHandler
```

to no success.

---

**Update**

I've found that setting `designMode = 'on'` is causing the problems. If I comment out the line that sets designMode to `'on'` then handling events works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I have a solution:

```
if(document.addEventListener)
{
    frames['writer'].document.addEventListener('keyup', updateStatus, false);
    frames['writer'].document.addEventListener('mouseup', updateStatus, false);
}
```

It works a charm!

Comment: For IE support, consider this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer) from developer.mozilla.org.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a function called document.onkeyup:

```
function document.onkeyup() {
  // do stuff
}
```

I've never seen that style before, but that was just something I found on Google...